# Python Pandas How to combine columns according to the condition of checking another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame:

```
value,combined,value_shifted,Sequence_shifted,long,short
12834.0,2.0,12836.0,3.0,2.0,-2.0
12813.0,-2.0,12781.0,-3.0,-32.0,32.0
12830.0,2.0,12831.0,3.0,1.0,-1.0
12809.0,-2.0,12803.0,-3.0,-6.0,6.0
12822.0,2.0,12805.0,3.0,-17.0,17.0
12800.0,-2.0,12807.0,-3.0,7.0,-7.0
12773.0,2.0,12772.0,3.0,-1.0,1.0
12786.0,-2.0,12787.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0
12790.0,2.0,12784.0,3.0,-6.0,6.0
```

I want to combine the long and short columns according to the value of the combined column

If df.combined == 2 then we leave the value long

If df.combined == -2 then we leave the value short

Expected result:

```
value,combined,value_shifted,Sequence_shifted,calc
12834.0,2.0,12836.0,3.0,2.0
12813.0,-2.0,12781.0,-3.0,32
12830.0,2.0,12831.0,3.0,1.0
12809.0,-2.0,12803.0,-3.0,6.0
12822.0,2.0,12805.0,3.0,-17
12800.0,-2.0,12807.0,-3.0,-1.0
12773.0,2.0,12772.0,3.0,-1.0
12786.0,-2.0,12787.0,1.0,-6.0
12790.0,2.0,12784.0,3.0,20.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use if possible `2,-2` or another values in `combined` column [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df['calc'] = np.select([df['combined'].eq(2), df['combined'].eq(-2)],
                       [df['long'], df['short']])
```

Or if only `2,-1` values use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['calc'] = np.where(df['combined'].eq(2), df['long'], df['short'])
```

Comment: Quick question: is there any pro/con of using `df['combined'].eq(2)` vs `df['combined'] == 2`?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco - Yop, obviously less typing if chain masks `df['combined'].eq(2) & df['aa'].eq(5)` vs `(df['combined'] == 2) & (df['aa'] == 5)`

Answer (score 1):

```py
df['calc'] = np.nan

mask_2 = df['combined'] == 2
df.loc[mask_2, 'calc'] = df.loc[mask_2, 'long']

mask_minus_2 = df['combined'] == -2
df.loc[mask_minus_2, 'calc'] = df.loc[mask_minus_2, 'short']
```

then you can drop the `long` and `short` columns:

```py
df.drop(columns=['long', 'short'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: `np.select` (as in jezrael's solution) is the intended function to do exactly what I have in my answer. Only I have it spelled out in several steps

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['calc'] = df['long'].where(df['combined'] == 2, df['short'])
```